# Java Method Returns Unbounded Type

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was reading this article, https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2010/10/25/using-builder-pattern-subclasses, about subclassing a builder class. I understood the article but there was one small bit that bothered me. There was this method,

```
public static Builder<?> builder() {
        return new Builder2();
}
```

When I changed `Builder<?>` to `Builder`, a raw type, the compiler would not compile the code. What is the additional information was passed to the compiler via with the additional `<?>`?

I have pasted the code here:

```
public class Shape {

  private final double opacity;

     public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {
         private double opacity;

         public T opacity(double opacity) {
             this.opacity = opacity;
             return self();
         }

 /*
         public T height(double height) {
             System.out.println("height not set");
             return self();
         }
 */
         protected T self() {
             System.out.println("shape.self -> " + this);
             return (T) this;
         }

         public Shape build() {
             return new Shape(this);
         }
     }

     public static Builder<?> builder() {
         return new Builder();
     }

     protected Shape(Builder builder) {
         this.opacity = builder.opacity;
     }
 }

 public class Rectangle extends Shape {
     private final double height;

     public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Shape.Builder<T> {
         private double height;

         public T height(double height) {
             System.out.println("height is set");
             this.height = height;
             return self();
         }

         public Rectangle build() {
             return new Rectangle(this);
         }
     }

     public static Builder<?> builder() {
         return new Builder();
     }

     protected Rectangle(Builder builder) {
         super(builder);
         this.height = builder.height;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Rectangle r = Rectangle.builder().opacity(0.5).height(250).build();
     }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this should only cause a warning. Is your compiler configured to stop on warnings? What was the error message?

Comment: Change Builder<?> to Builder you will see the error, 

Rectangle.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(Rectangle.builder().opacity(0.5).height(250);

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the generic part `<?>` of `Builder<?>`, all generic information is removed and the `T` in your `Builder` class becomes `Object` - `Object` does not have an `opacity()` method.

Comment: This was what I suspected. I am looking for more information regarding this. An URL to an article explaining this behavior would be perfect

Comment: @thlim Actually I think my answer is incorrect. You would probably get more and better answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: Off topic, sometimes I am confused as to where I should post my questions. One time I was suggested to post here instead SO for question like this. Nevertheless SO has more audience.

Comment: To simplify, SO is for questions about specific issues with a specific piece of code. Programmers is for higher level question such as design and architecture, algorithms etc. So in this instance SO would probably be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` symbol is a type variable. It's an unnamed one, meaning you can't refer to it in code, but the compiler still is going to use it, and substitute it with the actual type your `Builder` works with (such as `Rectangle`). The compiler can then use this additional type information, including the proper resolution of the `opacity` method.

Without `<?>`, this additional compile-time type information is lost, thus compiler needs to assume it works with plain `Object`. As a result, you'd explicit casting to invoke any method that `Object` class does not have.